# Firebug css js order vs real load order

Tags: javascript, css, firebug

I want to know the order firebug shows in script , css.Is it the real order in which 
the files are loaded or they are shown in sorted alphabetical order.

I want to know the sequence order how they are loaded instead of doing viewsource.

any inputs will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firebug's **Net** tab will show you the order in which the browser makes requests. You can filter based on Javascript, CSS, images, etc. This is the "real" order, not alphabetized.

Comment: i use net panel a lot but totally forgot about that. I can check there right..thanks. I was looking at css , script.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the net panel?  By default, it shows them in the order they are loaded.  However, you *can* click the different column headers to sort the lines.